# CISCO ASA5512-X no Console Output

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, management, network-access

Situation:
We bought new ASA5512-X. It worked everything okay. I had access over SSH on the ManagementPort which was directly connected to my PC. 
Then I realised there is a configuration already on it. I googled this: [Reset ASA How To](http://www.itnotes.eu/?p=599)So i wanted to erase the config with

```
> conf t

> write erase
```

because i read here [Write Erase Command](http://www.cisco.com/web/techdoc/dc/reference/cli/nxos/commands/fund/write_erase.html) that it will clear my configuration and I continued on with configuring everything new over Console Cable (I should have checked at this point if I can connect to ASA with Console Cable ...). What I didn't think off, that I will immidatly loose connection to the ASA. Then i realised the ASA is rebooting. Why? (ASA is on my Desk)

Now I am not able to get Access on Management Port via DHCP, nether static IP 192.168.1.X. Because there is no configuration -> `write erase`.

And now the strange thing is, **I can't even get Access via Serial Cable. That is my main prolem!

My Question is: How can i get Access again AND what does "`write erase`" really do? I don't think it's only clearing EVERY Configuration, can it be that it also cleared my disk?

Procedure: When I cannoct over console I do following:
I use old Server with WIN2012R2.
Connect blue Serial Cable to SerialPort on Server and on Console Port on ASA
Then I try to connect via Putty to ASA. (Used COM1, COM2. More comes aren't shown in Device Manager).

UPDATE: Today my USB-to-Serial Adapter Calbe arrived. I can now Access my old Router (so the connection is fine) but I can't connect to the ASA over the Consolee cable ... I rally don't know what's wrong. I also tested every Speed which is avaible from Tera Term Pro.

Comment: You need to try the various speed settings. Start with 9600, then increase it one step at a time up to whatever is the maximum for your serial port. 38400 and 115200 are popular choices, too.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. But i have never changed it. Isn't there a default of 9600? Which i always try. 
Do you know if there is ALWAYS an Output on Console Port? Even if their is a Hardware Error like a formatted Harddrive/Flash. Cause I'm really afraid that write erase have done this :s

BTW: Do you know other popular Speed?

Comment: As the others have told you, `write erase` only deletes the startup configuration.

Comment: I will try several speeds now. I will let you know if it worked!

Comment: I have tried every Speed provided from teraterm beginning by 110 ending by 115200 - no result.

Comment: You have a problem on your PC, either with the hardware or application. USB to serial adapters are known to be problematic. You should ask about getting help your PC hardware/software on [su] since that is off-topic here.

Comment: But i can connect to other Routers and i tried with 2 Cables `(FITD, Trendtech) and two Laptops - Windows7 and Debian ...

Comment: Another possibility is that the device failed on a restart. You would need to contact Cisco about repair or replacement  That's one reason you buy SmartNet (the main reason being software updates, which are especially important for firewalls).

Comment: okay. But when it fails on a Restart, wouldn't that mean that the green lights shouldn't be green? Software Update is only avaible if i pay for it? (soory i know its off topic).

Comment: I don't think anybody here can help you. You are going to need to bite the bullet and pay for some help. the `write erase` command only deletes the startup configuration, as sever people here have told you. It is rather foolish to pay a lot of money for a good firewall, but not purchase the SmartNet to keep the software up to date. That would also repair/replace your hardware in the event of a failure. Hindsight is 20/20.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think you are right, I have to pay for some help. Or send it back (ASA only one week old). But quickly back to the SmartNet. Without SmartNet i can't do Software Upgrades/Updates? Not even manually updating/upgrading?

Comment: SmartNet allows to access to the software updates, then you need to manually load them.

Comment: You are a real hero. Just checked your Profile. And thank you veery much for giving me information without getting annoyed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a broken ASA, I sent it back to the Factory and they got it repaired. The Putty Setting from *JFL* are working now, if anybody needs them.

Answer (score 1):

The default serial settings in Putty are not adapted to connect to a Cisco device.

Try those settings :
(I.E. change Flow control to "None")

[image]

Edit in response to the last sentence of the original post.

You should not be afraid to appear as "dumb". We all did mistake, often much more serious than this one. Only people that do nothing never do mistakes.

I would not trust at all someone that claims he never made error. It's a liar.

But I do trust people that do mistakes, endorse them, and do their best to correct them.

Errors are one of the best way to learn... (see you will learn how to connect to a Cisco device trough serial console, which is still a must-have skill in network engineering).

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. Unfortunately i have tried it with this configuration. No Result. Connection stays empty.

Comment: You don't have anything on console port event when you boot up the PIX? Can you try your serial connection on another device?

Comment: No. I tried it like 5 minutes before on our actual Router (1812). There I also get nothing. Only the green bar. So in conclusion I can say, my Putty is not working correctly. I am very young (19y) so i don't have much knowledge about Serial Cables. I greq up with USB ;-) but i made your Configuration on Putty and i only get green bar.
How do i figure out which Serial port is used?

Comment: you may try to go into the machine BIOS to see if the embedded com port is enabled and correctly configured. The com port that windows 2012 see may not be the one you try to connect to.

Comment: can you get a usb-to serial adapter? that would ease the com port identification.

Comment: Okay. The Problem is, i can't take the Windows Server offline. It's a productive one :s 
I will test it with USB-TO-Serial Adapter on Monday (ordered it today) then i can connect via my Laptop. 
But the command "write erase" deletes ONLY the configuration.
So if my connections is working i should see the ASA prompt?
Then i can co to the global config und conf t ? 
Because then i can activate SSH on the Management Port and don't need the Console Cable any more.
Is this right?

Comment: Funny, i ordered it like 10 Minutes ago. TrendNet TU-S9. This one should work. I have an old one here, which is from 200X and i don't even have a Driver or i know the model :s

Comment: It erase only the startup configuration and not the runinng one, therefor you cannot start over without rebooting first to clean the running-config.  Did you issue the "reload" command as stated in the link you provided? That actually means "reboot" on cisco devices.

Comment: What JFL said. `write erase` only kills the boot config, but your ASA should have kept working without any change - especially it should not have rebooted by itself. Reboot (reload in Cisco world) requires the `reload` command and a confirmation to work - so the behaviour of your device is really strange at all.

Comment: Ouh - write erase should only remove the startup? I thought every configuration. Maybe the system crashed at this very important point. Because i didn't came to point where it asks me to reload. 
All I wanna do now is get access to it ... But thanks that you prove me, that i didnt crashed to system to a state I can't recover. Cause I thought i have deleted very important files that the system can't boot anymore. I am very happy that the problem is the connection and not the ASA itselft. I will wait until monday and try to connect via USB-to-Serial.

Comment: I can now remember how we have done this in school. We also used a USB-To-Serial adapter. And we also used Putty, but we changed something in a File on Putty so we could access our Router. Can't remember what exactly. So i have to wait until Monday, then my adaoter will arive. Hope everything will work.

Comment: Today my cable arrived. But still no success. :(